# how to delete the outline of objects outside of a collection in python

Tags: python, collections, outliner

I make an object using blender

```
example = bpy.data.curves.new(name="example",type="CURVE")
bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_curve_add()
example_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name = "example", object_data = example)
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.objects.link(example_object)
```

Then I want to remove it. I already know how to remove it from the scene, but when I look at the Blender files, there is also another copy(?) of the same datas, under the `Curves` data group. I want to delete these as well, programatically. My question is: what function do I call to remove such elements, since they are outside of the scene or collection, and I could only find how to remove objects if they were in a collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice how you create a data element twice:

1. An object in `bpy.data.objects`.
2. A curve inside `bpy.data.curves`.

The former is a general purpose wrapper holding such properties as parenting information, transformation matrices, assigned materials, modifiers, constraints... The latter is the raw data, mostly about shape. So you remove the object by doing:

1. `bpy.data.objects.remove(`...`)`.
2. `bpy.data.curves.remove(`...`)`.

If you do only one of those then you will end up with either an empty object still visible in the outliner (if you removed the curve and didn't unlink the object from the collection), or the object will disappear from the scene and outliner, but the now orphaned data block containing curve information will still be in file (by default it won't be saved, however, so after reopening the project it will no longer be there; you can also purge orphans).